# Is it possible to set multiple keys to switch input language in windows 10?

Tags: windows-10

As Title. I want to use both Grave Accent and ALT + Shift to switch input language.
Is it possible to do that in windows 10? if it is possible. Could you please explain how?

Thanks all

Comment: You could use autohotkey to reassign the grave accent, but if you did it would no longer be possible to type `\``

Answer (score 0):

I think [this](https://www.top-password.com/blog/change-input-language-using-keyboard-shortcut-in-windows-10/) is what you are looking for.

Comment: this is not what I looking for. In that menu I can select only 1 method to switch input language. What I want is I can use both Grave Accent and ALT+Shift to switch input language.